# Create new timestamp in pandas based on occurence in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe-column with random timestamps and NaT values in between them:

```
timestamp             
01-01-2018 13:12:48
NaT
NaT
NaT
04-01-2018 08:15:12
NaT
Nat
```

I want to create another column that starts counting from 0 once there is a new timestamp in the timestamp column (col_A). I wouldnt mind if that column was a timestamp object but without the date (col_B). Is that possible?

```
timestamp            col_A  col_B             
01-01-2018 13:12:48  0      00:00:00
NaT                  1      00:01:00
NaT                  2      00:02:00
NaT                  3      00:03:00
04-01-2018 08:15:12  0      00:00:00
NaT                  1      00:01:00
Nat                  2      00:02:00
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an island-and-gap problem: every time `timestamp` is not null, it creates a new island. You usually solve these problems with a cumulative sum of some kind.

Try this:

```
islands = df['timestamp'].notnull().cumsum()
df['col_A'] = df.groupby(islands).cumcount()
df['col_B'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col_A'], unit='minute')
```

Comment: Thanks! I see how that works. Initially my timestamp was not in line with the index (which also contains timestamps). The resolution of the index was different from the timestamp column that I used to create col_A and col_B. I changed the timestamp back to an object to make ist work.